# How to use data to rewrite this json

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this json

```
      assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
        "Version" : "2012-10-17",
        "Statement" : [
          {
            "Action" : "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            "Condition" : {
              "StringEquals" : {
                "${replace(module.complete_eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:aud" : "sts.amazonaws.com",
                "${replace(module.complete_eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:sub" : "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"
              }
            }
            "Effect" : "Allow"
            "Sid" : "EBSDriverRole"
            "Principal" : {
              "Federated" : module.complete_eks_cluster.oidc_arn[0]
            }
          },
        ]
      })
    }
```

I tried to use data and write policy as

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]
    
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(module.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:aud"
      values   = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(module.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:sub"
      values   = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
    }
  }
}
    
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_driver_policy" {
  name   = "${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-driver-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ebs_csi_driver.json
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role" "ebs_csi_driver_role" {
  name                 = var.is_rapid ? "CUSPFE-${var.cluster_name}-ebs-csi-driver-role" : "${var.cluster_name}-vpc-cni-driver-role"
  assume_role_policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ebs_csi_driver.json
  permissions_boundary = var.is_rapid ? var.rapid_role_permissions_boundary : null
  tags                 = local.tags
}
    
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ebs_csi_driver_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_driver_policy.arn
}
```

But I am getting error as

```
     │ Error: creating IAM Policy (eks-ebs-csi-driver-policy): MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy statement must contain resources.
      │     status code: 400, request id: 754503a6-6130-44a0-880a-c7cde1f0e73b
      │ 
      │   with module.eks.aws_iam_policy.ebs_csi_driver_policy,
      │   on .terraform/modules/eks/iam.tf line 20, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_driver_policy":
      │   20: resource "aws_iam_policy" "ebs_csi_driver_policy" {
      │ 
      ╵
      ╷
      │ Error: creating IAM Role (eks-ebs-csi-driver-role): MalformedPolicyDocument: Missing required field Principal
      │     status code: 400, request id: c4ebff87-a8b3-4028-b3d5-1bdcfca167b1
      │ 
      │   with module.eks.aws_iam_role.ebs_csi_driver_role,
      │   on .terraform/modules/eks/iam.tf line 25, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ebs_csi_driver_role":
      │   25: resource "aws_iam_role" "ebs_csi_driver_role" {
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You are missing the `Principal` in the data source.

Comment: Did the JSON policy work previously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example in JSON, the data source is not defining the `principals` at all. This can be fixed by adding it to the policy data source:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ebs_csi_driver" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(module.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:aud"
      values   = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(module.eks_cluster.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer, "https://", "")}:sub"
      values   = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"]
    }

    principals {
      identifiers = [
        module.complete_eks_cluster.oidc_arn[0]
      ]
      type = "Federated"
    }
  }
}
```